# Is There a Single-File Based Graph Database Management System?

Tags: graph

I am considering using a graph database management system (DBMS for brevity) as an application file format for my single-user desktop application.

Is there a [single-file based](https://www.sqlite.org/onefile.html) graph DBMS ([the "equivalent" of SQLite](https://sqlite.org/appfileformat.html) for graph DBMSs)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick google search [showed this result](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=10991751)

- [TinkerPop3](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.1.0-incubating/#tinkergraph-gremlin)
- [Embedded Neo4j (java)](http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/#tutorials-java-embedded)
- [Arango DB](https://www.arangodb.com/) which does [graphs](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.2/Manual/Graphs/)